# docker-compose ignoring startup order established by depends_on

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose.yml with three services: a Node app, a Mongo database, and [waisbrot/wait](https://github.com/waisbrot/docker-wait) to wait for the Mongo server to start listening before starting the app.

When I run `docker-compose up`, compose starts building and starting the app service immediately instead of bringing up its dependencies first. I get no output at the console to suggest compose is trying to start either of the other containers.

The stack fails to start because the app server crashes when it can't connect to Mongo.

Here's my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'
services:
  wait:
    image: waisbrot/wait
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    environment:
      - TARGETS=mongo:27017
  app:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - wait
  mongo:
    image: mongo:3.2
    volumes:
      - /data/db
```

My intent is to start the mongo service first, start the wait service second, the start the app last. Looking at the output and even watching `docker stats`, it seems only the app service is being started. Here's the output of `docker-compose up`:

```
Building app
Step 1 : FROM node:6.6
 ---> c0d8845263e3
Step 2 : COPY ./package.json /app/package.json
 ---> Using cache
 ---> db47c6c65663
Step 3 : WORKDIR /app/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 30c3cadc2680
Step 4 : RUN npm i
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5ae6a18b2100
Step 5 : COPY ./src/ /app/src/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> dd64329a5fe2
Step 6 : COPY ./config/ /app/config/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1945706cdaac
Step 7 : COPY ./public/ /app/public/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> af6f6b7075c1
Step 8 : EXPOSE 3030
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4ecec8df6ef7
Step 9 : RUN npm start
 ---> Running in 04a543b58d85
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@3.10.3
npm info using node@v6.6.0
npm info lifecycle family-communication@0.0.0~prestart: family-communication@0.0.0
npm info lifecycle family-communication@0.0.0~start: family-communication@0.0.0

> family-communication@0.0.0 start /app
> node src/

Feathers application started on localhost:3030

/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:261
        process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                      ^
MongoError: failed to connect to server [mongo:27017] on first connect
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:313:35)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:260:12)
    at Connection.g (events.js:291:16)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:162:49)
    at Socket.g (events.js:291:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at connectErrorNT (net.js:1015:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)

npm info lifecycle family-communication@0.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.20-moby
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! family-communication@0.0.0 start: `node src/`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the family-communication@0.0.0 start script 'node src/'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the family-communication package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node src/
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs family-communication
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls family-communication
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c npm start' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Why is this not working as I'd expect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
RUN npm start
```

that command in your Dockerfile is actually starting your webserver at *build* time, when the other containers don't exist yet.  Probably you want

```
CMD npm start
```

Comment: Also, the 'wait' container will not do what you hope it will do.  You use that in one command to make sure that a container started, and then run your other container in the next command.  Docker-compose will just start them without waiting for any to exit.  You will have to add retry/connect logic to your webapp, or an entrypoint in your webapp container.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I completely missed that. Thank you! Not sure I follow you on the wait container though. You're saying depending on that container will not ensure my mongo container has started before the app does? I followed this example: https://medium.com/@edgar/how-to-wait-for-a-container-to-be-ready-before-starting-another-container-using-docker-compose-92bab2fc1633#.fmp63xl5h

Comment: It will START before the app does, but may or may not be ready to accept connections.  If you notice, he uses the 'wait' container in a seperate command... he runs `up`, then runs `wait`, then runs hist tests.